# Alternative for Word-wrap property in CSS for ITextSharp application

Tags: c#, html, css, itext

I am trying to wrap textual content within a specific width , but wasn't able to wrap the content within limit. Does anyone have an alternative to achieve word-wrap?

Comment: Considering that you also tagged this with html and css, does that mean you're trying to convert html to pdf?

Comment: Yes I was trying to Convert HTML to PDF, were I was facing issue when there is a continuous word, word-wrap property wont Work with Itext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should show us what you've already done, 
give us some code.

You can also try out pdfHTML (it's the newest iText add-on that converts HTML to pdf).

http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML

pdfHTML also allows you to convert html code to iText IElement implementations, which you can then style like regular iText objects. We have some good tutorials that show you how to work with the basic building blocks.

http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/examples

Comment: Sorry Joris, one of our service consumes HTML and generates PDF, I dont have much knowledge on it.

Comment: Check out our website, it has a ton of examples. And it'll convert HTML to pdf. HTML5 + CSS3